# rename certain value in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following panda Series:

```
print(df.head())
          Country  Energy Supply Energy Supply per Capita  % Renewable
0     Afghanistan   3.210000e+08                       10    78.669280
1         Albania   1.020000e+08                       35   100.000000
2         Algeria   1.959000e+09                       51     0.551010
3  American Samoa            NaN                      ...     0.641026
4         Andorra   9.000000e+06                      121    88.695650
```

How can I rename Afghanistan to Afghanistan_new?
I can set the index:

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
```

and then try to rename the country the following way:

```
df['Afghanistan'].rename('Afghanistan_renamed')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, one reason this can get tricky is that you name to alter the second value in your first list.  So, imagine your data like this:  [ [0,"Afghanistan"], [1,"Albania"] ].  To edit Afghanistan directly, you have to edit the data structure for df[0][1].  I am sure there are wrapper methods too, but that is what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use if need replace `index`:

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
df = df.rename(index={'Afghanistan':'Afghanistan_renamed'})
print (df)
                     Energy Supply Energy Supply per Capita  % Renewable
Country                                                                 
Afghanistan_renamed   3.210000e+08                       10    78.669280
Albania               1.020000e+08                       35   100.000000
Algeria               1.959000e+09                       51     0.551010
American Samoa                 NaN                      ...     0.641026
Andorra               9.000000e+06                      121    88.695650
```

and for [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) column:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace({'Afghanistan':'Afghanistan_renamed'})
df = df.set_index('Country')
print (df)
                     Energy Supply Energy Supply per Capita  % Renewable
Country                                                                 
Afghanistan_renamed   3.210000e+08                       10    78.669280
Albania               1.020000e+08                       35   100.000000
Algeria               1.959000e+09                       51     0.551010
American Samoa                 NaN                      ...     0.641026
Andorra               9.000000e+06                      121    88.695650
```

Comment: Yes, sure. Ony extend `dict` like `{'Afghanistan':'Afghanistan_renamed', 'Albania':'Albania111'}`

Comment: Could it be done without setting the index to Country?

Comment: I think yes, only in second solution omit `df = df.set_index('Country')`

Answer (score 0):

**You can just use replace() instead rename()**:

df['Country'].replace({'Afghanistan':'Afghanistan_renamed'}, inplace=True)